# Google App Engine return Permission Denied

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an ASP.NET Core web application hosted on the GoogleCloud App Engine.

The application has a function that creates and displays a PDF.

Locally it works, however in the GCP it is giving permission denied according to the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DALPP.png)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I will post my comment as an answer, as it is too long for the comment field.

[“Permission Denied” errors](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/troubleshooting#how_do_i_fix_permission_denied_errors) typically mean the caller doesn't have the right Google Cloud IAM permission on certain resources.

When developing for GAE you have to check whether the libraries you are utilizing within your ASP.NET app are compatible with GAE and additionally authorize the requests performed to GAE.

Does the pdf document get stored in a Database? If yes, does your application have all permissions required to read and write files to the Database?

Could you please specify your configurations, as well as provide the .yaml file  and the corresponding code of your application for further clarifications?

Comment: Hi,thank you for reply. The web app create and return as FileContentResult:

Comment: Response.Headers.Add(@"Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}.pdf", Uri.EscapeDataString("receita.pdf")));

Comment: Could you please specify your dependencies as well (meaning the libraries you are utilizing along with your requirements.txt)?